# What colors are Babylon 2 and 3?

Tags: babylon-5

Each Babylon station is colored a different color.  We know:

- Babylon 1 is red, as seen in *In The Beginning*.
- Babylon 4 is green, as seen in *Babylon Squared* and *War Without End* (and possibly others)
- Babylon 5 is blue, as seen in... let me think...

What colors are Babylon 2 and 3?

Comment: We never saw either of them, I don't if JMS ever commented on it, but based on the order of colors for the ones we saw, I've seen several sites guess that Babylon 2 would have been orange and Babylon 3 yellow.

Comment: Do we even know if Babylons 2 and 3 got far enough along in the construction process to have had their exterior cladding applied before they were destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the first Babylon station was far enough along to be red.  Also I doubt that 1 - 3 were as close to Babylon 4 as JMS implies.   But submitted as an example of the only canon thing I could find on the topic.  Some fan did some cool fan fiction stations once but I couldn't find those either.

From JMS Speaks archive

> Re: ATTN: JMS Question About Babylon 1-3
> Posted on 4/4/1996 by jmsatb5@aol.com to rec.arts.sf.tv.babylon5.moderated
>
> "What were the designs for Babylon 1-3. Were they based on the Babylon 4
> model or the Babylon 5 model? "
>
> They were designed to eventually become what we saw in B4. None of the
> first 3 got much past the early stages of construction.
>
> jms